# I want to choose hiredate between '20-FEB-81' AND '01-MAY-81'

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I want the names of the employees, job, hiredate between '20-FEB-81' AND '01-MAY-81', and in ascending order

query I ran with error

```
SQL> select ename, job, hiredate where hiredate between '20-FEB-81' AND '01-MAY-81'   from emp;
select ename, job, hiredate where hiredate between '20-FEB-81' AND '01-MAY-81' from emp
                        *
 ERROR at line 1:
 ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected


 SQL>
```

My table
     SQL> select empno, ename, job, hiredate, sal from emp;

```
 EMPNO ENAME      JOB       HIREDATE         SAL
 ---------- ---------- --------- --------- ----------
  7839 KING       PRESIDENT 17-NOV-81       5000
  7698 BLAKE      MANAGER   01-MAY-81       2850
  7782 CLARK      MANAGER   09-JUN-81       2450
  7566 JONES      MANAGER   02-APR-81       2975
  7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN  28-SEP-81       1250
  7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN  20-FEB-81       1600
  7844 TURNER     SALESMAN  08-SEP-81       1500
  7900 JAMES      CLERK     03-DEC-81        950
  7521 WARD       SALESMAN  22-FEB-81       1250
  7902 FORD       ANALYST   03-DEC-81       3000
  7369 SMITH      CLERK     17-DEC-80        800

 EMPNO ENAME      JOB       HIREDATE         SAL
 ---------- ---------- --------- --------- ----------
  7788 SCOTT      ANALYST   09-DEC-82       3000
  7876 ADAMS      CLERK     12-JAN-83       1100
  7934 MILLER     CLERK     23-JAN-82       1300

 14 rows selected.

 SQL>
```

Comment: Please read the error description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The WHERE part goes **after** the FROM part.

```
select ename, job, hiredate 
from emp
where hiredate between '20-FEB-81' AND '01-MAY-81'
```

Note that your date literals may not always work if the NLS settings change. It is highly recommended to use to_date() instead.

```
select ename, job, hiredate 
from emp
where hiredate between to_date('20-FEB-81', 'DD-MON-RR') AND to_date('01-MAY-81', 'DD-MON-RR')
```

But this is still subject to language settings problems, better not use month *names* at all:

```
select ename, job, hiredate 
from emp
where hiredate between to_date('20-02-81', 'DD-MM-RR') AND to_date('01-05-81', 'DD-MM-RR')
```

Comment: The `TO_DATE` calls should probably use the 'DD-MON-RR' format mask.  DD-MON-YY converts '20-FEB-81' to February 20, 2081.  DD-MON-RR converts '20-FEB-81' to February 20, 1981 which is, presumably, what is desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> select * from emp where year(hiredate)>=1981 and year(hiredate)<=1983;
```

Output:

```
+-------+--------+-----------+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
| EMPNO | ENAME  | JOB       | MGR  | HIREDATE   | SAL     | COMM    | DEPTNO |
+-------+--------+-----------+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+
|  7499 | ALLEN  | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 1981-02-20 | 1600.00 |  300.00 |     30 |
|  7521 | WARD   | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 1981-02-22 | 1250.00 |  500.00 |     30 |
|  7566 | JONES  | MANAGER   | 7839 | 1981-04-02 | 2975.00 |    NULL |     20 |
|  7654 | MARTIN | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 1981-09-28 | 1250.00 | 1400.00 |     30 |
|  7698 | BLAKE  | MANAGER   | 7839 | 1981-05-01 | 2850.00 |    NULL |     30 |
|  7782 | CLARK  | MANAGER   | 7839 | 1981-06-09 | 2450.00 |    NULL |     10 |
|  7788 | SCOTT  | ANALYST   | 7566 | 1982-12-09 | 3000.00 |    NULL |     20 |
|  7839 | KING   | PRESIDENT | NULL | 1981-11-17 | 5000.00 |    NULL |     10 |
|  7844 | TURNER | SALESMAN  | 7698 | 1981-09-08 | 1500.00 |    0.00 |     30 |
|  7876 | ADAMS  | CLERK     | 7788 | 1983-01-12 | 1100.00 |    NULL |     20 |
|  7900 | JAMES  | CLERK     | 7698 | 1981-12-03 |  950.00 |    NULL |     30 |
|  7902 | FORD   | ANALYST   | 7566 | 1981-12-03 | 3000.00 |    NULL |     20 |
|  7934 | MILLER | CLERK     | 7782 | 1982-01-23 | 1300.00 |    NULL |     10 |
+-------+--------+-----------+------+------------+---------+---------+--------+

13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```